# Giving margin-right value more than its parent width

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
      Div
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
}  

div{
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    margin-right:400px;
}
```

What really happens when giving margin-right to div? does it have effect at all? what about giving more margin-right, like 600px. then what happens?

**OR** That would be nice if you consider a div that exactly fits in its parent. like:

```
div{
    width:400px;
    background:blue;
    padding: 98px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Now what happens with giving margin-right to div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the margin-right itself. You cannot see the effect of margin-right because the 'width' property of div causes the margin of div to have more than 10px distance from the right wall of the body. Consequently, it causes the margin-right property not to have any visual effect.

In order to see the effect of margin-right, remove width property or increase it to a value which causes the div right border to come close to the body wall (or to attach it to the body wall). Then, set the margin-right to a larger value (to make the change more clear). Here is the modified code (the only change in the following code is that I have removed the width property in order to increase the width of div to occupy the whole width of the body):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/94h3mkrp/1/)

css change :

```
body{
    border: 5px dashed blue;
}

div {
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #308014;
    margin-right:100px;
    /*margin-left:50px;*/
    /*margin-top:10px;*/
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: One thing, i noticed, is that, it simply ignores margins higher than that value. no overflow occurs. or margin apparently doesn't go under body. it simply ignores. (eye experience). but with span or other inline elements, overflow happens when, for example, span gets a lot of right margin. Am I correct?

Comment: you can accept the answer if it is correct to help other users

Answer (score 0):

The as it is this property will have no effect at both examples!

Try to play with this one [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/94h3mkrp/) !

```
`Margin-right` will have effect when you use along with `float:right`
```

property and will come `400px` from right the whole div!

Comment: I know it has effect with float:right. I want to know what happens in two examples i gave.

Comment: Realy nothing effect i see.